# Extract BFMI from stanfit object in rstan

Tags: stan, rstan

After fitting a model in stan using `stan()`, how can I extract the BFMI for each chain? From this conversation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/stan-dev/uJhsapVwlk8, it appears that BFMI at one point displayed when using the print method. However, that doesn't appear when using `print(stanfit)`, and the BFMI doesn't show up when using `get_sampler_params(stanfit)`.

Is there a way to get the BFMI from a stanfit object?

rstan version: 2.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not returned but if you want to do it yourself, see [this block](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/develop/rstan/rstan/R/misc.R#L1636) of code.